# A kind of addeventlistener in c++

Tags: c++

I think it doesn't exists in c++ but it would be very convenient.
Say I have a class:

```
class SPRITE
{
    void RunTo(POINT pt);
    SPRITE(MAINCLASS* main);
}
```

And a main function:

```
SPRITE sprite=new SPRITE();
while(1)
{
    GetCursorPos(&pt);
    FrameMove(frame,pt);
}
```

So if I want to call `SPRITE::RunTo` with the cursor position I need to call it from the main loop which is simple with one class but less with many.

The good thing I'm thinking about is something like that:

```
SPRITE::SPRITE(MAINCLASS* main)
{
    main->AddListener(main::Framemove(int frame,POINT pt){ RunTo(pt); });
}
```

It's a pure invention but maybe there's something that can do the same ?

Thanks

Comment: C++ has neither `FrameMove` nor `AddListener`.

Comment: Look up "pointer to member function".

Comment: @harper I know it is just a notation to make my problem understandable.

Comment: @Rusty I'll see

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to Rusty, this is what I made:

In main.cpp:

```
struct PFUNC
{
    void (*func)(void* classvar, void* arg0);
    void* classvar;
}
vector <PFUNC> onFrameMove;

void FrameMove(int frame,POINT pt)
{
    #some jobs here

    for(int i=0;i<onFrameMove.size();i++)
         onFrameMove[i].func(onFrameMove[i].classvar, onFrameMove[i].arg0);
}
```

in SPRITE.cpp:

```
SPRITE::SPRITE(MAINCLASS* main)
{
    PFUNC fc;
    fc.classvar = this;
    fc.func = &FrameMoveCB;
    main->onFrameMove.push_back(fc);        //add to the main job
}

void FrameMoveCB(void* classobject, void* arg0)   //callback to translate the void*s
{
    SPRITE* Sprite= (SPRITE*)classobject;

    Sprite->FrameMove(*(POINT*)arg0);     //call the true method
}

void SPRITE::FrameMove(POINT pt)
{
    //more job here
}
```

So my main loop handle all the job and I don't have to modify it while adding new classes.

If someone have simpler I'll be happy, but that's good I think (and it work)